# Submit is always false. displays error: "you have not submitted the form!"; I am using Wampserver to test following code on local machine

Tags: php, html

I am using Wampserver on local machine to test the code below but after  clicking on submit I get message "you have not submitted the form!"

```
<body>
<!-- Start code for the form-->
<form method="post" name="myform" action="form.php">
    <p>
        <label for='name'>Enter Name: </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="name">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for='email'>Enter Email Address:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="email">
   </p>

    <p>
        <label for='message'>Enter Message:</label> <br>
        <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="submit">
</form>
</body>

<!--form.php-->

<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        echo "you have not submitted the form!";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "you have successfully submitted the form!";
    }

?>
```

Comment: I think your conditions are reversed. Put the if code in else and the else code in if and try again.

Comment: I would expect your if to be backwards, submit is only set after a submit.

Comment: This is a strange conditions content as mentioned... LOL. If user sumbited, of course the message should be `echo "you have successfully submitted the form!";` . Since PHP recognized `$_POST['submit']`. Assuming you are not joking with us...

Answer (score 0):

change your code to the following

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // if the form was submitted and the submit button was clicked
    echo "you have successfully submitted the form!";
}
else 
{
    echo "you have not submitted the form!";
}
```

?>